# Special folder information in OS

Tags: .net

Does using Environment.SpecialFolder gurantee the right folder information on all windows OS's?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. It uses the Win32 API [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx) which is available on Windows XP RTM and all downlevel Windows versions with IE 5.0 installed.

Comment: Also note that the .NET Framework requires at least IE 5.0, so there is no worry about whether this function exists or not (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

I found these *special* folder location confusing sometimes. I created a sheet comparing the folder locations on Windows XP and Vista. That may be useful to you.
[Here is the link.](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p4j46E_RfMgTVcQzHZRRmDQ)